# Slicing operation in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am passing a batch of images to my neural network. Let's say the shape of a batch is `(4, 224,224,3)`. Now I want to apply slicing operation on my batch so that I can get two tensors of shape `(2,224,224,3)` respectively. How can I do this using `tf.slice()` or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you rather want to use [`tf.split`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split). E.g in your case,

```
tf.split(my_tensor, 2)
```